# Drop-down menu and radio buttons not sticking

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, sticky

I am creating an html form that has php in it to get information from the end-user. After the user submits the information, a message is posted at the top. If the user did not enter values into any of the fields after hitting submit, an error message will show at the top and the values already entered should still be present in the inputs.

The issue I'm having is making the checkbox stick.

I posted my html first:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="rainGauge" value="Make a Rain Gauge" <?php if(in_array("rainGauge", $_POST['interests'])) echo 'checked'; ?>> Make a Rain Gauge </label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="thermometer" value="Make a Thermometer"<?php if(in_array("thermometer", $_POST['interests'])) echo 'checked'; ?>> Make a Thermometer </label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="windsock" value="Make a Windsock"<?php if(in_array("windsock", $_POST['interests'])) echo 'checked'; ?>> Make a Windsock</label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="lightningMouth" value="Make Lightning In Your Mouth"<?php if(in_array("lightningMouth", $_POST['interests'])) echo 'checked'; ?>> Make Lightning In Your Mouth</label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="hygrometer" value="Make a Hygrometer"<?php if(in_array("hygrometer", $_POST['interests'])) echo 'checked'; ?>> Make a Hygrometer </label><br>
```

Here is my php

```html
  
  //foreach loop to show selected Interests
if ((!empty($_POST["interests"])) && ($stopPost !="Y"))
{
  echo "You have chosen the following workshops:";
  foreach($_POST["interests"] as $checked => $interests)
  {
    echo "<p><em>" . $interests ."</em></p>";

  }
}
```

I'm unsure why what I'm using isn't working. I've searched solutions online and this seemed to be what worked for most people, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `$_POST["charleston"]` (and the others) are never set, those are the `values` of your `<select>`. Your `<select>` is named `closestCenter`, so check for `$_POST['closestCenter']`. Same for `isset($_POST["Y"]`, you need check the `name` of the input element, not its value

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the new code in addition to the existing code. One thing: `... == "Charleston"` It never is `Charleston`, the value _you_ put in there is `charleston`. And add a space before your `value=...` attributes

Comment: I fixed what you mentioned and now the radio buttons and drop down menu are working perfect! Any idea on how to fix the checkboxes though? I've struggled with that one most because of the array

Comment: @Christineh - look within the `setstate` function I posted below for how to process the checkbox array...

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have chosen has the potential to become unwieldy - all the inline conditions and echo statements make it quite hard to follow and also quite bloated. You could easily use PHP to generate the content dynamically - either from statically declared arrays, database lookup or reading from a source file. The benefit of this is that you can modify things very quickly simply by changing the source values.

For instance, using statically declared arrays:

```
<?php
    /*
        Simple function that does the POST lookup and determines if the supplied value is equal to the POST value.
        If it is then the default checked/selected string will be returned.
    */
    function setstate( $name, $type, $value ){
        if( isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) ){
            switch( $type ){
                case 'checkbox':
                    if( is_array( $_POST[ $name ] ) && in_array( $value, $_POST[ $name ] ) ) return 'checked';
                    if( $_POST[ $name ]==$value )return ' checked';
                break;
                case 'radio': if( $_POST[ $name ]==$value )return ' checked';
                case 'select': if( $_POST[ $name ]==$value )return ' selected';
            }   
        }
        return '';
    }
    
    /* easily extensible arrays to govern displayed content */
    $centres=array(
        'charleston'    =>  'Charleston',
        'summerville'   =>  'Summerville',
        'mtPleasant'    =>  'Mt. Pleasant',
        'burton'        =>  'Burton',
        'orangeburg'    =>  'Orangeburg'
    );
    $membership=array(
        'Y'         =>  'Yes',
        'N'         =>  'No',
        'signUp'    =>  'Sign me up.',
        'nfi'       =>  'Do not remember'
    );
    $interests=array(
        'rainGauge'         =>  'Make a Rain Gauge',
        'thermometer'       =>  'Make a Thermometer',
        'windsock'          =>  'Make a Windsock',
        'lightningMouth'    =>  'Make Lightning In Your Mouth',
        'hygrometer'        =>  'Make a Hygrometer',
        'hydro'             =>  'Make a Hydroponoic grow system',
        'gokart'            =>  'Make a motorised Go-Kart'
    );
?>
```

And then the HTML

```
<form method='post'>

    <section data-id='Centers'>
        <label>Your closest center:
            <select name='closestCenter'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>Please select Center
                <?php
                    foreach( $centres as $key => $centre ){
                        printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s', $key, setstate('closestCenter', 'select', $key ), $centre );
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </section>
    
    <section data-id='Membership'>
        <label for="member">Are you a member?
            <?php
                foreach( $membership as $key => $value ){
                    printf('<input type="radio" name="member" value="%s" %s/> %s',$key, setstate('member', 'radio', $key ), $value );
                }
            ?>
        </label>
    </section>
    
    <section data-id='Workshops'>
        <?php
            foreach( $interests as $key => $interest ){
                printf('<label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="%s" %s/>%s</label>', $key, setstate('interests', 'checkbox', $key ), $interest );
            }
        ?>
    </section>
    
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

I hope it helps a little